# How to change the color interface of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, interface

[image]

I want to get an interface like the one on the big screen on Ubuntu, how can I do that? I searched around and learned how to change the background and the foreground color, but this one is just great. Even the sidebar and the title bar is kindda blue. Any idea how I can get this kind of interface?

Thanks. :)

Comment: That looks like a bunch of blue terminal windows and not an interface. The launcher is transparent, so what you see is the background color. Get yourself a blueish wallpaper, change the terminal background color, ...and you are done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely that version of Ubuntu is using a custom theme. Browse [ubuntuthemes.org](http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/) and find a theme you like. Download the zip folder and paste the contents into `~/usr/share/themes`.

You will need a program to set the theme. I recommend Gnome Tweak Tool. To install Gnome Tweak Tool open terminal and install it through apt:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once installed run Gnome Tweak Tool and you should be able to select the theme you copied to `~/usr/share/themes` in the drop down menus in the appearance tab.